# Nexus Private Registry "blob upload invalid"

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype

I'm using Nexus OSS 3.24.0-02 and trying to

`docker build -t mynexusip:8083/mydockerimage:version` and
`docker push mynexusip:8083/mydockerimage:version`

Expected result is "pushed successfully" but it gives error
`blob upload invalid: blob upload invalid`

Full console output log is like below,

```
docker push mynexusip:8083/myapplication:a5212b386b323189950f78577cc292137b314601
The push refers to repository [mynexusip:8083/myapplication]
067995e8fe00: Preparing
8e45792fc9b6: Preparing
8b65bf832c89: Preparing
db672395134b: Preparing
27e8da285ed6: Preparing
579a8f1d6a12: Preparing
15e45d99c926: Preparing
0cf75cb98eb2: Preparing
814c70fdae62: Preparing
15e45d99c926: Waiting
0cf75cb98eb2: Waiting
814c70fdae62: Waiting
579a8f1d6a12: Waiting
db672395134b: Layer already exists
8e45792fc9b6: Layer already exists
27e8da285ed6: Layer already exists
067995e8fe00: Layer already exists
8b65bf832c89: Layer already exists
579a8f1d6a12: Layer already exists
0cf75cb98eb2: Layer already exists
15e45d99c926: Layer already exists
814c70fdae62: Layer already exists
blob upload invalid: blob upload invalid
```

I use Git commit id for versioning, and 8083 is the port of my docker-private repository. When I googled this error, I found a few suggestions about "Allow Redeploy" in the configuration section of repository but I have already set that.

[image: nexus repository settings]

By the way, the version of Nexus has been upgraded recently(it was 3.15). After that it started to give error like I mentioned. I don't know if it's related or not but just in case I want to share it. Is there anyone who have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I found that it was a known bug and it is fixed with coming release.

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/release-notes#ReleaseNotes-BugFixes

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-20640

**EDIT:** I realized that this bug "**blob upload unknown**" is different from my problem which is "**blob upload invalid**" but with the 3.28 release it is fixed. You can find details in the link below.
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-25378

Answer (score 4):

This would happen if you are trying to push the same image multiple times or with different tags
solution :
navigate to nexus repo to your image location
you will find 2 folders

- manifest
- tag

manifest try to delete unwanted blob files.

now you are all set you can push image now